# Resources aimed at slavic speakers

Tags: resource-request, russian

Do you know any good resources for learning Russian aimed at (native) speakers of some other slavic language? I have a few yugoslav textbooks, for instance "Ruski u 100 lekcija" (Špis, Gavela) which seems good.

But I think I could make good use of a good Russian textbook written in e.g. Czech. I wouldn't understand the Czech - I'm just looking for a good pedagogical approach for someone who already speaks a language relatively similar to Russian. If not in vocabulary, any slavic speaker is fluent in almost all the gramatical structures present in the other ones, so the approach to learning the language should be different than for a native French-speaker, let's say.

There are many books and other resources out there. I'm asking specifically for what you would say are the really **good** ones, worth spending some money on. Thank you.

Comment: Start from this topic: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/833/resources-for-learning-russian

Comment: Thank you. I already looked at it, there is a german textbook there, but I am looking for textbooks in Slavic languages.

Comment: i believe it's possible to fetch some titles with Google search and have a look at their samples which could exist on Google books or elsewhere

Comment: What is your native (L1) language?

Comment: Czech is my native language, but I don't find it to be much relative to Russian. From a fluent Russian speech, I can usually understand few words, but not much sentences. Moreover, there are many false friends. My favorite one is Czech word „úžasný“, which means “great” or “awesome”, but in Russian, there is some similar (maybe same) word that means “awful”.

Answer (score 3):

Czech is member of Western Slavic group, Russian is Eastern, the book you have (I assume Croatian?) is Southern Slavic group. They are quite different. Did you tried to understand some Czech? Explanation of Russian grammar in Czech might be confusing.

Did you considered http://steen.free.fr/interslavic/index.html - "Slavic Esperanto" as a starting point?  At least to get used to Cyrillic, if you don't know it already?

And then, dive directly to Russian. Depending on your L1, it might be possible to find a language exchange partner. Start with books for children, which have explicit stress. Syllable stress is very important in  Russian, and not shown in standard texts. So what you need is texts with the stressed syllables.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the "Радионяня" it was Soviet broadcast for primary school.
I have read that foreigners used to learn Russian using its recordings.
You can find them on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ETmt3KO78oY&list=PLhHRrQ7q1-VwBpcNjYfdFY-mH41luQ7RA)